# Mediaplayer not working for all buttons

Tags: java, android, button, media-player

I'm working on a drumpad with multitouch. I have used an inner class which extends a button:

```
package dubstep.brendan;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestButton extends Button {
private MediaPlayer mpButtonClick =MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),R.raw.firework);


public TestButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        mpButtonClick.start();



    }
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        mpButtonClick.pause();
        mpButtonClick.reset();
        mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.firework);

    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
}
```

I have twelve other classes that extends buttons and uses mediaplayer, But only seven of them work. The rest don't. Although If I delete the mediaplayer object from either one of the 7 working classes, one of the classes that wasn't working, starts to work.

Additionally, I get these errors in my log:

```
MediaPlayer(226):   info/warning (1, 26)
PlayerDriver(30):   Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info             PVMFErrResource
MediaPlayer(226):   error (1, -17)
PlayerDriver(30):   PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
MediaPlayer(226):   create failed:
MediaPlayer(226):   java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:644)
MediaPlayer(226):   at dubstep.brendan.TestButton8.<init>(TestButton8.java:11)
MediaPlayer(226):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
MediaPlayer(226):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
MediaPlayer(226):   at  android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
MediaPlayer(226):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
MediaPlayer(226):   at      dubstep.brendan.MultitouchtestActivity.onCreate(MultitouchtestActivity.java:33)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
MediaPlayer(226):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
MediaPlayer(226):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
MediaPlayer(226):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
MediaPlayer(226):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
MediaPlayer(226):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
MediaPlayer(226):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Notice that it is "TestButton8" class for my 8th button that has an error, and all the classes that follow also have the same problem, and as I mentioned above, If I delete mediaplayer object, For example, If I delete mediaplayer from TestButton class above, "TestButton8" class will start to work. Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't have the solution, but you may want to consider a `SoundPool` for a drum pad, I think it would be more appropriate. A mediaplayer is quite a heavyweight object, and SoundPool is supposedly better for multiple simultaneous short sounds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim! I did try soundpool, But I'm not able to use it in the button class for some odd reason. Could you give me an example please? Maybe I'm doing it wrong.